# Регистрация в GWT

Tags: gwt, java

Здравствуйте! У меня есть GWT-приложение, нужно добавить страницу регистрации пользователя, страницу входа. Напишите, пожалуйста, подробно, как это всё делать..

Comment: @1tatiana9, не совсем ясно, что конкретно вызвало затруднения. А также опишите систему более подробно.

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, как сделать регистрацию пользователей в GWT-приложении. Использую Google App Engine ещё. Там есть встроенная авторизация пользователей через Google-аккаунт, но мне нужно сделать свою.где-то было написано, что нужно использовать jsp. если использовать jsp, то посоветуйте как...

Comment: @1tatiana9?, не могу не обратить внимания на ваш ник =) вопросом убили, а комментарий вообще без слов оставил =)

я думаю, нужно создать.... ее даже объяснять начинать боюсь =) пожалуй и не буду... =) думаю меня поймут..

Answer (score 1):

Готовый пример из практики GWT, JSP, Spring Security:

**login.jsp**. Форма входа в систему. Обратите внимание, форма отправляется на url `/j_spring_security_check`.

```
<div id="login-form">
  <form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />">
    <label for="j_username">Логин:</label>
    <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" class="login-field"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="j_password">Пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" class="login-field"/>
    <br/>
    <div id="input">
      <input type="submit" value="Войти"/>
    </div>              
  </form>
</div>
```

**security.xml**. Конфигурация для Spring Security. Предполагается, что`App.html` это и есть наше GWT-приложение.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

  <http access-denied-page="/error403.jsp" use-expressions="true">  
    <intercept-url pattern="/App.html" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
     <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll"/>

    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
                default-target-url="/App.html" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/App.html"/>
  </http>

  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Кстати на JavaCodeGeeks есть довольно развернутая [статья](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html) на эту тему.

Comment: @Nofate, извините, не понял, а пароль здесь пересылается в открытом виде ?

Comment: Да, это ведь обычная form-based authentication. Но защититься можно обернув соединение в SSL.

Comment: SSL не спасает от fake.

Comment: от какого рода fake?

Comment: Подставили картинку (форму ввода) получили пароль.

Comment: Вообще-то SLL-сертификаты как раз и должны спасать от фишинговых сайтов
![SSL-сертификат](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/3282/sslcert.png)